# ASP.NET Core Web App UI part supports https only but API calls inside Web App supports http only

Tags: asp.net-core

I need to develop an asp.net core web app. Besides UI part of the web application, it needs to support api calls also. When the user accessing the web application, it should only support https. However, when other old web applications make api calls to this web application, it should support http only.

The web application will be deployed to linux box using the kestrel for hosting. Right now, aps.net core 3.1 is used for the web application. The kestrel-related part in the launchSettings.json are:

```
"WebApplication": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  }
}
```

I know I can use UseHttpsRedirection to make sure web application will direct all UI accessing to https only. But how to make api calls go through http only?

Can anyone shed some light on how I can achieve this? Some code snips will be extremely appreciated.

Comment: Well, you could ommit `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` from your program.cs file and can set `"useSSL": false` in your `launchsettings.json`. this might help you to call non https calling. In addition, you could change your port as well. Could you please share which port you are currently using? Usually port 5001  and 5000 allocated for SSL. You can [`have a look here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-7.0#configureiconfiguration)

Comment: Right you are, it would be great if you could include your `launchSettings.json` with us and update the question.

Comment: The related part from launchSettings.json is added to the question

Answer (score 0):

> When other old web applications make api calls to this web
> application, it should support http only.

Well, it can be configured in numerous way. As you can see in applicationUrl two port has been assigned by default which are "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000"

If you call your API by http port it would listen to that port as well. However, if you specifically want to configure [kestrel server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-3.1#endpoint-configuration) you can either configure launchSettings.json or in program.cs file.

**Kestrel server appsettings.json For HTTP:**

```cs
"Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://localhost:53211"
      },
      "useSSL": false
    },
```

**Note:** As launchSettings.json file doesn't publish, so Kestrel  the option in  appsettings.json we can set above configuration. [You can check here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-3.1#configureiconfiguration)

**Kestrel server program.cs For HTTP:**

```cs
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).
            ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(serverOptions =>
            {
                serverOptions.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 5080);
             
            }).UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
```

**Note:** Once you modify above ConfigureKestrel in your program.cs file ommit app.UseHttpsRedirection(); because it would use https middleware to search https port. Before, implementaing above non http configure, please [have a look our official document to know details how the configurations works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-3.1#bind-to-a-tcp-socket).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. The requirement I have is that when accessing the web application through UI, it should strictly support https only, no HTTP at all. With the implementation you are describing, will it meet the requirement? Sorry if I am asking a silly question, I am digesting the related knowledge.

Comment: In this scenario, you have two way, one is to call API from your UI with this configured http URL `http://localhost:53211` another way is, if you have any specific IP of your UI app then in middleware you have to check and decide whether it should http or https. For this implementation details, it wowuld great if you ask new question because two different topics are hard to explain in single one.

Comment: In fact, the current deployment supports both HTTPS and HTTP already. The new requirement is to cover the security hole. So my original question here is trying to see if it is possible to do partial HTTPS only. I am new to this area, so not sure it is even possible.

Comment: You can check the URL and then can enforce https by using Path.StartsWithSegments.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else comes to this page, I post here what I found that solved my problem. I did some reading based on the info provided by @Md Farid Uddin Kiron and found out that ASP.NET Core has everything I need. All I need is to do conditional HTTP to HTTPS redirects by using the MapWhen extension method of IApplicationBuilder.

This is a code snip (the API calls started with /api will not be redirected to HTTPS while others do):

```
app.UseWhen(context => 
    !context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api"), appBuilder =>
{
    appBuilder.UseHttpsRedirection();
});
```